# In bash, reading from a socket through exec, via process substitution, doesn't work,

Tags: bash, scripting, unix-socket

I feel a bit dumb asking this, but here it goes.

I'm trying to implement a very simple ftp client in bash, for testing purposes, and thought I could use a clean approach at reading/writing from/to the socket using `exec` and process substitution, as follows.

```
exec 3<> /dev/tcp/$host/$port
exec 4< <(dos2unix <&3)
exec 5> >(unix2dos >&3)
```

I would then read from `fd 4` and write to `fd 5` in order to send commands and receive responses.

Alas, whilst writing works like a charm, reading doesn't: `dos2unix` just gets stuck as if waiting for input that never arrives. Using any other command in place of `dos2unix` shows the same behavior, but **using a real character device** in place of `/dev/tcp`, say `/dev/urandom`, works as expected.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong, or what is the problem?

Comment: try `stdbuf -o L`. Or really just `sed -u`. Other then that, please post a [MCVE].

Comment: @KamilCuk you probably meant `stdbuf -o 0` there? It actually helped, thanks! Do you want to post that as an answer rather than just a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Alas, whilst writing works like a charm, reading doesn't:

In most linux shells by default the standard output stream of commands are line buffered. In most linux shells by default the standard output stream of commands in a pipe are block buffered (except the last command).

To restore line buffering of a command it's common to use `stdbuf -oL` utilitye.